# Saving data to PostgreSQL when typing a slash command in Slack

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, bots, slack

I'm trying to build a bot for Slack that has some slashes commands. I'm totally new to Node.js and Slack, and I'm having huge problems to make it work, starting with the fact I cannot even know the reasons it fails.

I'm storing my bot in Heroku and I have a `status` table in there as well. I want to, when typing `/here`, to store the user's username and add a status 'here' to the database for further selection. My code's like this:

```
app.post('/here', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.user_name;

    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('INSERT INTO status(username, status) VALUES($1, $2)', [username, 'here']);

        var botPayload = {
            text: 'Your status is now set to HERE'
        };

        return username !== 'slackbot' && !err
            ? res.status(200).json(botPayload)
            : res.status(200).end();
    });
});
```

This piece of code is based on a tutorial I found summed with other tutorials of how to connect and insert data into PostgreSQL, but when typing it in Slack channel, I receive the HTML of the Appliation Error page.

This is my full code. Only one file so far.

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200);
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/hello', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.user_name;
    var channel = req.body.channel_name;
    var botPayload = {
        text: 'Hello ' + username + ', welcome to channel ' + channel + ' :-)'
    };

    return username !== 'slackbot'
        ? res.status(200).json(botPayload)
        : res.status(200).end();
});

app.post('/here', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.user_name;

    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('INSERT INTO status(username, status) VALUES($1, $2)', [username, 'here']);

        var botPayload = {
            text: 'Your status is now set to HERE'
        };

        return username !== 'slackbot' && !err
            ? res.status(200).json(botPayload)
            : res.status(200).end();
    });
});

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `heroku logs`? Is there anything interesting there? Another first debugging step I might take is to comment everything out of one of your functions and replace it with a simple `res.status(200).send('TEST');` to make sure that works. Then you can build back up to the full code you want to write.

Comment: Also, does the other method (`/hello`) work?

Comment: Yes, the /hello works and returns the text without problems. And, no, I will try to check Heroku logs and try that out.

Comment: Yes, I do see an error on the line of the query. `client.query('INSERT INTO status(username, status) VALUES($1, $2)', [username, 'here']);` with TypeError of `Cannot read property 'query' of null`

Comment: Great! So that means `client` is null. Which I imagine happens when there's a connection error. So you might need to print out the value of `err`. (By the way, I think you should call `done()` somewhere in there when you're done with the Postgres connection, but that's a separate issue.)

Comment: I've removed `pg.defaults.ssl = true;` and now, after some modifications, I receive the error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`. it means it just cannot connect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112742/discussion-between-gabriel-m-fernandes-and-smarx).

Comment: I've made it work! I had to create a variable `con` and store it either `process.env.DATABASE_URL || postgres//username:password@host/database` Is that the way to do so?

Comment: I think you can use `heroku config:set DATABASE_URL=whatever` to set make it available via the environment variable in Heroku.

Comment: Thank you @smarx, it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

> This piece of code is based on a tutorial I found summed with other tutorials of how to connect and insert data into PostgreSQL

It does not seem that way, as you made too many errors in your database code:

1. You are not checking for `err` after the connection, so if your connection fails, the rest will fail as well
2. You are not providing any callback on event handlers to get the result of the query you are executing
3. You are not releasing the connection back to the pool by calling `done()`

All of the above is necessary, and would be included in any manual that's out there, starting from the `pg` driver itself: [Client Pooling](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres#client-pooling).

Comment: I've found this example and rewritten my code adding these missing things. What solved for me was to remove `pg.defaults.ssl = true;` and add `var con = process.env.DATABASE_URL || postgres//username:password@host/database;`

Comment: @GabrielMFernandes Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which may simplify your database code a lot ;)

Comment: I will, much appreciated.